# Can't execute select query on some columns of table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with 43 columns. When I execute "Select * from My_Table", it works; And shows data of all columns.
But if I perform "Select" query on some of the columns ( In my case, the first 29 columns of the table)
I receive an error that says "INVALID IDENTIFIER".
Other columns work just fine.
I can't perform "group by" or "order by" using these 29 columns either.
What do you think is the problem?
Any help is appreciated.
Some screenshots are attached for better understanding.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looking at screenshots, it seems that you created table using mixed letter case and enclosed column names into double quotes. If that's so, well - that's usually bad idea in Oracle as you'll always have to identify columns that way: match letter case and use double quotes.

Therefore, that would be e.g.

```
select "Order_Id", "Customer_name", "DATA_DATE"
from your_table
```

Looks *awful* ... will you remember that *customer name* doesn't have initial capital letters, but e.g. *trace number* does?

For you own sake, if possible, drop that table and create a new one as

```
create table your_table
  (order_id      number,
   customer_name varchar2(20),
   trace_number  number,
   ...
  );
```

and reference such a table and columns using any letter case (as it'll work because - by default - Oracle stores names in uppercase (into data dictionary), but lets you reference them any way you want):

```
select order_id, CUSTOMER_name, TRacE_NumBER ...
```